# What's the best way to manipulate the product list in the category page?

Tags: magento2, products, category-products, extend

How can I manipulate the list of products which will be shown on the category page?

Answer (score 0):

You can change position of the products in the category. If you go to Products > Categories, then choose your category. Then click on Category Products and change position of the products in the order you want.